# What to do when the VPS you have purchased comes with a control panel that does not support your application runtime environment?

Tags: web-hosting, plesk, control-panel

I am totally new to web-hosting.

Recently, I have purchased a domain name and a VPS that comes with Plesk Onyx 17.0.17. After consulting the technical person from where I have bought the VPS, they tell me Plesk does not support TomEE, but my application has to be running under TomEE PluME server.

My question is: does it means that my application will not be able to be running on this VPS anymore? Is it a must to have a control panel for a VPS? Or I can actually configure the runtime environment by my self without the control panel?

Comment: In most cases, if you have root or administrator access, you can install whatever applications you like manually, barring conflicts with what's already installed. You just won't see the option to administer the application in the control panel. You might also need to check firewall rules after major control panel updates or re-installs in case they've been reset. If you  have the option to not have a control panel installed, then the issue of conflicts and system alterations will be reduced, but you'll have to administer everything yourself manually.

Comment: @dan Thank you for your reply. I think I have the administrator access as I can actually install anything by my self. But if I am not using the control panel to host my application, how am I able to point the domain name to my application? The domain name I have bought has already pointed to my VPS by the technical person, but my question is, how to actually make it point to my application? so when user enters `www.example.com` it will actually redirect to my application

Comment: That seems like a separate question... Domain names use DNS records to point to IP addresses. If your VPS only has one IP address and it isn't a shared IP address with other VPS accounts or other domains in your VPS, then you really don't  have to do anything further. The exception to that is if your control panel is being used to host the name servers for your domain, and then you remove the control panel. In that case, you'll need to either manually add name servers, or simply use the one provided by your domain Registrar (or use a third-party DNS provider or CDN).